# In appendix package, how to get Chapter headers, as well as section headers

Tags: header-footer, appendix

I am using the appendix package to put three appendices at the end of my thesis. I have it set up the way I need - with each appendix lettered rather than numbered, but the subsections are numbered, etc. But while the header for the section (individual appendix) shows, the header for the 'chapter' (Appendices) doesn't. I have tried using \markleft(Appendices), which worked for an abbreviations chapter at the start but that doesn't seem to work with the appendices, at least the way I have set it up.

Is there a way to get the word 'Appendices' where the chapter header would normally go, i.e. on the right hand page header? But not using fancy header.

The main code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book} %,PageStyleII,times,numbering,print,custombib
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{a4paper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={small}, skip=1pt, singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={small}, skip=1pt, singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font={small}, skip=1pt, singlelinecheck=false}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{enumitem}

%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}

\usepackage{makecell}
% ******************************** Main Matter *********************************
\mainmatter
% ********************************** Appendices ********************************

\begin{appendices} % Using appendices environment for more functunality

\include{Appendix/appendix}
%\include{Appendix2/appendix2}

\end{appendices}
```

In the appendix document, I have:

```
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}  
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
\counterwithin{table}{section}  
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}  

Blah blah

%********************************** %First Section  **************************************
\section{First Appendix}
```

Comment: The `\appendixpage` is implemented as a `\part*`.  `\chapter` still works, but uses `\@chapapp` set to `\appendixname`.

Comment: I am a newbie to LaTeX so I don't know what your comment means to amend my code to do what I want. I googled but it didn't help. :-) I have tried putting \begin{appendices} then \markboth{APPENDICES}{???} which gives me the 'chapter title' APPENDICES on the left hand page but I can't get the section title on the right hand page - I don't know what to put in the second bracket and nothing I have tried works.

Comment: Possibly you want subappendices instead of appendices.

Comment: Currently there is no word in the header on the left hand page where the Chapter name normally goes, just a page number, but the section name and page number on the right hand page. I would like the word 'Appendices' on the left hand page and the section name (as usual) on the right hand page. Is there a way to do that with the code I have posted to show how I have set up my appendices?

Comment: I have set up my appendices as three sections. But there is no chapter title. Just \begin{appendices} then some text and then the sections. Using \markboth{\appendixname}{???} gives me the word Appendix on the lefthand pages, which is great, but I still can't get the section name on the right hand page. Do you know what I should put in the second bracket to get that?

Comment: In book class, you should use `\chapter` instead of `\section` as your baic unit.  The section name will apear normally, but it takes a page.  Try `\gdef\leftmark{\appendixname}` instead.

Comment: I see what you mean about using chapter. I tried \begin{appendices} then \chapter*{Appendices} then \markboth{APPENDICES}{\thesection} and that seems to give me what I need. Thanks for your help and pointing me onto the right track. Much appreciated.